# How to diff ansible vault changes?

Tags: git, diff, ansible, ansible-vault

I'd like to see the actual git commit changes in the ansible vault file.

Is there an easy way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can do this very neatly, so that the normal git tools like `git log` and `git diff` can see inside the vaulted files, using a custom git diff driver and `.gitattributes`.

- Make sure that your vault password is in `.vault_password` and that that file is *not* committed - you should also add it to `.gitignore`.
- Add a `.gitattributes` file that matches any files in your repository that are encrypted with ansible-vault and give them the attribute `diff=ansible-vault`. For example, I have:

  ```
  env_vars/production.yml diff=ansible-vault merge=binary
  env_vars/staging.yml diff=ansible-vault merge=binary
  ```

  You can also use wildcarded patterns - the first element of each line, the pattern, follows the same rules as `.gitignore` files. The `merge=binary` option tells git not to attempt to do a three-way merge of these files.
- Then you have to set the diff driver for files with attribute `diff=ansible-vault` to `ansible-vault view`:

  ```
  git config --global diff.ansible-vault.textconv "ansible-vault view"
  ```

And that should be it - when git is calculating diffs of the files your pattern matches, it'll decrypt them first.

Comment: It's also good to add `merge=binary` filter to prevent git from 3-way merging of encrypted files and `git config diff.ansible-vault.cachetextconv false` to prevent caching sensitive information: https://selivan.github.io/2016/11/29/ansible-human-readable-git-diff-for-vault.html

Comment: My `PAGER` was `most` instead of `less`. Executing a `git diff` made me stuck in the `Vault password: ` prompt. I had to set my git pager to use `cat` by running the command `git config --global core.pager cat`

Comment: @Selivanov Pavel Thanks for that tip - I've updated the answer with that.

Comment: @GMaster : you can use your favorite pager and make ansible-vault use `cat`. Just set PAGER variable before command: `git config --global diff.ansible-vault.textconv "PAGER=cat ansible-vault view"`

Comment: @Selivanov Pavel: I tried that several times and it didn't work, git kept using `/usr/bin/most` instead of `cat`. Using `git config --global core.pager cat` to explicitly tell git to use `cat` as the pager worked for me.

Comment: Is there a way to configure this so that it *does* allow merging of the decrypted text content?  Does that need a separate mergetool configured or something?

Comment: If only I could apply a "thousand times this" sticker.

Comment: I had to set the ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE environment.

Comment: me too @BARJ: `export ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_password`

Comment: Additionally to the specified `diff.ansible-vault` command you can append `--vault-password-file=.vault_password`, or as has been suggested below by @victor-schröder set the corresponding property in the `ansible.cfg`.

Comment: One more hint: If you have vaults with different passwords, you can use `vault_identity_list=foo@/path/to/vaultfile1,bar@/path/to/vaultfile2` ([doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-vault-identity-list)). This works even if your vaults don’t have IDs, since apparently all identities will be attempted (i.e., the labels `foo` and `bar` are arbitrary and have no effect).

Comment: I am a bit curious about the vaule password file naming. Is `.vault-password` a standard file like `.dockerignore`, `.env`, `.gitattributes`

Comment: @MarkLongair - I suggest to NOT put .vault_password but instead to `apt-get install pinentry`. May I update your reply with a phrase saying you can do .vault-password but you should rather pinentry?

Comment: In vscode only staged files get encrypted.

Answer (score 10):

So after some digging I constructed the non-trivial solution.

First of all store your vault password into the (.gitignored) `.vault_password` file.

In the following example a `HEAD` and `HEAD~2` versions of the file  `inventory/group_vars/xyz/vault.yml` are vimdiff-ed:

```
vimdiff \
  <(ansible-vault view --vault-password-file=.vault_password \
    <(git show HEAD:inventory/group_vars/xyz/vault.yml)) \
  <(ansible-vault view --vault-password-file=.vault_password \
    <(git show HEAD~2:inventory/group_vars/xyz/vault.yml))
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `atk-git-diff` utility from  https://github.com/dellis23/ansible-toolkit

[image: This]

[image: Becomes]

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, it's worth to mention how to configure the diff for ansible-vaulted files globally. For example, I work with really a lot of ansible repositories over here and almost all of them have some vaulted secrets. So what I want is my configuration to be global and portable from one machine to another.

In your `~/.gitconfig` add these sections:

```
[core]
    # The following line defines a global .gitattributes file
    attributesfile = ~/.gitattributes

[diff "ansible-vault"]
    textconv = "ansible-vault view"
```

For this to work, you need some naming pattern for ansible-vaulted files, which is something good that you should do anyways. In my case, I like to name them with the extension `.vault.yml`. So my `~/.gitattributes` file looks like this:

```
*.vault.yml diff=ansible-vault merge=binary
```

Finally, to avoid typing the password all the time, make sure you have a file in a convenient place in each repository (normally something like `.vault`, placed at the root). This file must contain the password in plain text (properly `.gitignore`d, of course) or an executable script that produces such password.

Having that in place, go ahead and tell ansible to use the `.vault` file, by adding the following line to the global or local `ansible.cfg`:

```
vault_password_file = .vault
```

Done. Now running `git diff` will produce the readable diff that you would expect from non-vaulted files :)

Answer (score 1):

A hint for Windows users:
When running on windows you have the problem, that ansible-vault is not available. But you can install it inside your WSL.
After installing ansible-vault in WSL, the following is working for me

.gitattributes

```
**/vault.yml diff=ansible-vault
```

.gitconfig

```
[core]
  attributesfile = ~/.gitattributes
[diff "ansible-vault"]
  textconv = sh -c 'cat $0 | wsl ansible-vault decrypt --output - --vault-password-file=~/.vault_pass'
```

The vault password must be inside the wsl in ~/.vault_pass