# I keep getting a password prompt when I try to git-log an ansible-vault file

Tags: git, ansible, git-diff, git-log, ansible-vault

I followed the instruction here:

[How to diff ansible vault changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937195/how-to-diff-ansible-vault-changes)

but I keep getting a prompt to put in the ansible-vault password.

This is the command I run that prompts for the vault password:

git log -p staging.yml

What am I doing wrong?  I tried putting in the the pager as cat and less like the comments show and it still prompts for the vault password...can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I am using mac os x sierra...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set [vault_password_file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#vault-password-file) config option or `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE` environment variable to point to your vault password file.

In case of answer you linked to, it should be:

```
vault_password_file = .vault_password
```

Comment: This is what I already have in my .bash_profile:   ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=~/.vault_password  any other ideas?

Comment: Do you `export` it? Like `export MYVAR=value`.