# How can I `git diff` changes to rails 5.2 credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, credentials, git-diff, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I want to be able to diff the changes to my encrypted `config/credentials.yml.enc`.

`git diff` alone shows the difference to the encrypted file contents. I want to see the plaintext changes.

How can I get a human readable diff of the `config/credentials.yml.enc` file?

Comment: I've attempted to solve this via `.gitattributes`, by specifying `bin/rails credentials:show` as the diff `textconv` function for `config/credentials.yml.enc`, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39511274/885540.

However the `git diff` command fails with the following error as `bin/rails credentials:show` does not accept a path argument. (Unlike `ansible-vault view`).

Answer (score 13):

This will work if you use `rails encrypted:show` instead of `rails credentials:show` as it takes a file as an argument.

For a global configuration add to your .gitconfig

```
[diff "enc"]
  textconv = rails encrypted:show
  cachetextconv = false
```

and then in `~/.config/git/attributes` (or if you want to do it per project, put the following in a `.gitattributes` file at the root of your git project)

```
*.yml.enc diff=enc
```

Comment: Thanks. `rails encrypted:show` was exactly what I needed. Though I'd probably recommend `cachetextconv = false` to avoid caching sensitive data, and the config changes will need to be in `.git/config` unless you have an include for `.gitconfig` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330114/885540. Also the attributes can be defined in `.gitattributes` if you want those to track with the repo.

Comment: What is the `*.yml.enc diff=enc` for? It works without it (for me)