# How to diff Ansible vault changes using Mercurial?

Tags: ansible, mercurial, diff, ansible-vault

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39511274) answer tells how changes in encrypted `Ansible vault` can be diffed when using `Git`. Is it possible to get same results when using `Mercurial`?

I am using Mercurial `3.7.3` and Ansible `2.7.0`.

Comment: I bet you can do this with the extdiff extension: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension

Comment: @ngoldbaum is correct I think